# How to listen with node.js and redis Laravel 5 events

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, redis, laravel-5

In Laravel 5 not implemented ShouldBroadCast method, any idea how I can implement it manualy?

Here is my try.

This is handler for `ProjectNotificationEvent`:

```
<?php namespace App\Handlers\Events;

use App\Events\ProjectNotificationEvent;

use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeQueued;
use App\Notification;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis;
class NotifyUserAboutGroup {


        CONST CHANNEL = 'update.group';
    public function handle(ProjectNotificationEvent $event)
    {


            foreach ($event as $events){
                $redis = Redis::connection();
                $redis->publish(self::CHANNEL, $events->name);

                }
     }

}
```

This is node.js:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new Redis();
redis.subscribe('update.group', function(err, count) {
});
redis.on('message', function(channel, message) {
    console.log('Message Recieved: ' + message);
    message = JSON.parse(message);
    io.emit(channel + ':' + message.event, message.data);
});
http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Listening on Port 3000');
});
```

And on client side in my view I have this:

```
var socket = io.connect('127.0.0.1:3000');

            socket.on("update.group:App\\Events\\ProjectNotificationEvent", function(message){
            // increase the power everytime we load test route
            console.log(message);
        });
```

Problem is on client side `console.log` don't return anything.

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
var socket = io.connect('127.0.0.1:3000');

socket.on('message', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Please try this